# wx.Frame and threading in the same class

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm trying to create a class that handles wx.Frame and Threading at the same time (I tried to user Visual(threadins.Thread, wx.Frame) too, but I had no success. I really wouldn't want to use wx.CallAfter and I'd like to handle it in one class only. When I run the code, everything works fine, but the Close Method crashes the programand the frame remains open. Where am I wrong?

```
import threading
import wx

class Visual(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, title):
            screenWidth = 500
            screenHeight = 400
            screenSize = (screenWidth,screenHeight)
            self.app = wx.App(False)
            self.frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY,title, size=screenSize)
            panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)
            self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                     )
            self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Name', width=125)
            self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'DDD')
            self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Phone')
            self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, 'Desc', width=125)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
            panel.SetSizer(sizer)

            self.ready = False

            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.close)
            self.start()
    def close(self, event):
        print("Close")
        self.frame.Destroy()
        self.app.Destroy()
        self.app.ExitMainLoop()

    def run(self):
            self.frame.Show(True)
            self.ready = True
            self.app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   visu = Visual(title='Test')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I agree with the answer from MikeDriscoll but I wanted to suggest that once you call Destroy() on a wx object you shouldn't use it at all any more.  Every wx object is backed by a C++ proxy object, which is possibly dead or in an unusable state after calling Destroy.  The code in your close method uses self.app after you destroyed it.  You might get away with that sometimes but it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wxPython requires its main loop to be in the main thread, much like every other desktop GUI toolkit (i.e. PyQt, Tkinter, etc). You should only start threads after wxPython's main loop has been started. In other words, threads should be started from within wxPython.

wxPython has three thread-safe methods. They are as follows:

- wx.CallAfter
- wx.PostEvent
- wx.CallLater

Anyway, this will almost certainly require you to have a thread class and one or more wxPython related classes. This is normal and the recommended practice. See the following links for more information:

- https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- https://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui

Comment: bah i had it mostly typed up(you must have an alert of some sort for wx ;P ) ... it might be worth mentioning wx.CallAfter (although im sure all those links do)  as an aside @bruno Mikes Blog (see second link) is an amazing resource for all things wx!

Comment: I just got lucky...but I'm sure your answer would have been great too!